# How is number of Elasticsearch number of slices are calculated based on the number of shards?

Tags: elasticsearch, slice

I am using Elasticsearch version elasticsearch-7.13.4. I don't find any precise answer to it on the internet. Is there any formula for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying concept is called ["sliced scroll"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/paginate-search-results.html#slice-scroll) and is independent of the number of shards. From the linked documentation:

> By default the splitting is done on the shards first and then locally on each shard using the _id field with the following formula: slice(doc) = floorMod(hashCode(doc._id), max) For instance if the number of shards is equal to 2 and the user requested 4 slices then the slices 0 and 2 are assigned to the first shard and the slices 1 and 3 are assigned to the second shard.

However, when using [automatic slicing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-automatic-slice) (i.e. `slices=auto`), Elasticsearch will pick the number of shards as the number of slices

> Setting slices to auto will let Elasticsearch choose the number of slices to use. This setting will use one slice per shard, up to a certain limit. If there are multiple sources, it will choose the number of slices based on the index or backing index with the smallest number of shards.

> Query performance is most efficient when the number of slices is equal to the number of shards in the index. [...] Setting slices higher than the number of shards generally does not improve efficiency and adds overhead.

Comment: Hi @Val thanks for the quick reply. I have seen in the past when working with the spark based applications, we see this error ```The number of slices [2666] is too large. It must be less than [1024]``` when we halved the number of spark partitions the number of slices also reduced to half. Do you happen to know anything regarding that?

Comment: I don't know in the context of Spark. However, if you really need to increase the amount of slices, you can do so by setting `index.max_slices_per_scroll` in your index settings.